# Create Blur solid colored background using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need help getting to apply glossy blur effect to solid color background using css:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.overlay {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znp73yr6/

Comment: have you checked this : http://codersblock.com/blog/creating-glow-effects-with-css/

Comment: Can you give an example of what this would look like? I'm left to guess here

Comment: I guess you can use `filter: blur(5px);` for it.

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't even sure what he meant. But I did try to help. Hopefully I got it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code snippet below, that uses `filter: blur(5px);` for blur effect

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

.blur {
    background: blue url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAcHL.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div class="overlay">
      Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can see that all .overlay content has been blured which I need to be front clear visible ;)

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim got you, I changed snippet so only background is blurred.

Comment: Great if you don't need to support IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: @JonP Thanks, I added few browser specific options for filter, should work on Edge and IE11, but not sure about older versions.

Comment: Edge has partial support for filter. No IE support for any version.

Comment: I believe filter: blur works only for image backgrounds and not for background/text/border/etc colors. This means that filter: blur can't be used to have acrylic dialogs/context menus on top of other dialogs or main UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `rgba` for colors to give them opacity. This makes the background look blurry.

```
background: rgba(0,0,255, 0.5);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/znp73yr6/1/

Comment: This however does not give a blurry effect in that the things behind your semi-transparent layer will not be blurred (  transparency != blur )